# MySql Subquery IN returns the first result, not all results

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TrackID, Name, Artist, Album, TotalTime, TrackNumber, TrackCount
FROM tracks
WHERE TrackID IN (SELECT Tracks FROM playlists
                  WHERE ID='f8ad830c-e2d6-11e1-99d7-00132094'
                  LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY Artist, Album, TrackNumber
```

Executing that returns the first row from the 'tracks' table to contain any of the results returned from the subquery. As of now, the Subquery returns:

```
41646,41696,41698,41700,41702,41704,41706,41708,41710,41712
```

When I put the above value returned from the subquery into the original query, in place of the subquery, it returns all the rows I would expect.

Why does the subquery limit the results returned to the first result, but replacing the subquery with the result returned (when ran in PHPMyAdmin) returns all of them?

Comment: This is happening, most probably because, your `Tracks` is being selected as a single string of text, instead of comma delimited numbers like this: `'41646,41696,41698,41700,41702,41704,41706,41708,41710,41712'`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TrackID, Name, Artist, Album, TotalTime, TrackNumber, TrackCount 
  FROM tracks 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(TrackID
                  , (SELECT Tracks
                       FROM playlists 
                      WHERE ID='f8ad830c-e2d6-11e1-99d7-00132094' 
                      LIMIT 1
                    )
                  ) > 0
 ORDER BY Artist, Album, TrackNumber 
;
```

Comment: I wouldn't leave it in this form. But this will likely be the easiest for you to understand, in the form closest to your attempt.

Comment: As you noted previously, breaking up the playlist into a list of one row per track is the more natural structure and will likely make more effective use of proper indexes, with a simple JOIN in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You say `limit 1` in your subquery. So, you get only 1 trackid and thus only one track.

You can either split the tracks up into multiple rows, so for one playlist you have as many rows as there are tracks, or you can split your tracks string into a temporary table. Look at [MySQL: Split comma separated list into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936088/mysql-split-comma-separated-list-into-multiple-rows) for example or search for "split string into rows"

Comment: There is a single row, with a comma deliminated list. The single row contains the comma deliminated list. But, I also tried removing the LIMIT 1 and the same result happened.

Comment: So `tracks` has all `trackid`s seperated by comma?

Comment: Yes. It's literally the string I put above with the 5 digit numbers.