# Sql dividing one record into to many records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table t1 sql records

```
user_id    tags
  1     <tag1><tag2>
  1     <tag1><tag3>
  2     <tag2><tag3>
```

I want to divide this records into multiple records and do distinct on it.
I want to know how to divide the records based on tags <> into another table t2

I need ouput like this in table t2

```
user_id    tags
  1     <tag1> 
  1     <tag2>
  1     <tag1>
  1     <tag3>
  2     <tag2>
  2     <tag3>
```

Can u guys give me some sql query to do??

Comment: How tags are separates ? is it in one column ?

Comment: Not one columns, Separate them into new multiple records with its user_id into another table t2

Comment: I meant in T1 right ?

Comment: It's better to use table like `t2` (pairs of `user`-`tag`), than keep all user tags in one field. Redesign your tables if you can.

Comment: Its not problem if it is done in table t1 or need to create new table t2

Comment: Actually I am not good student in sql, I am not able to write proper query for it

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936088/mysql-split-comma-separated-list-into-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,'<',2) as tag
FROM
    t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,'>',-2) as tag
FROM
    t1
```

**UPDATE:** for distinct values you can use :

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    tag
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,'<',2) as tag
    FROM
        t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        user_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,'>',-2) as tag
    FROM
        t1
) as tmp
    GROUP BY
        user_id,
        tag
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates if necessary

Comment: given the example of desired output its not needed to remove duplicates, that is why i didn't use `DISTINCT`

Comment: OP's question says "I want to divide this records into multiple records and do distinct on it."

Comment: indeed your right but his output isn't distinct , but i will update the query