# IN() with REPLACE() doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql

This code is work normally 
`SELECT 2 IN('1','2','3')` and the result is `1` that means the condition is true but something I don't understand.

I have a `associated_roles` table with data like this.

```
-------------------
|role_col         |
-------------------
|1,2,3,4,5        |
-------------------
|1,2              |
-------------------
|1,2,3,4,5,6,9,46 |
-------------------
|1,2,3,5,4,46,333 |
-------------------
```

The code `SELECT replace(role_col,',', '\',\'') from associated_roles` will return

```
--------------------------------
|role_col                       |
--------------------------------
|1','2','3','4','5              |
--------------------------------
|1','2                          |
--------------------------------
|1','2','3','4','5','6','9','46 |
--------------------------------
|1','2','3','5','4','46','333   |
--------------------------------
```

Finally I want to get row contain `2` and with `IN` and I have no idea why the below code doesn't work properly.

`SELECT * from associated_roles where 2 IN(replace(role_col,',', '\',\''))`

It's return nothing like this

```
--------------------------------
|role_col                       |
--------------------------------
|                               |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: where do you have a column name called `2`?

Comment: the `2` just a value want to check if it's in a comma separate string, it's not a column

Comment: Your data model is terrible you should consider using normalisation. `IN()` operator works on records not comma separated values.. You are looking for the function `FIND_IN_SET` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set ) which is designed to work with comma separated values

Comment: @HoaiNgo then you're using IN wrong - IN works like this: WHERE `col_name` IN (wanted_value_1, wanted_value_2);

Comment: thank for the recommendation, but `FIND_IN_SET` make the performance slower than using the other function

Comment: It doesn't matter that you use the `col_name` or single value like `2`, you can double check at https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php @treyBake

Comment: "but FIND_IN_SET make the performance slower than using the other function " How do you compare performance from a working function vs a function that does not work on your current data model? .... it's not the FIND_IN_SET what makes things slow it's your comma separated values data model which can be hard to index it's can be done with MySQL's generated columns but do you really want to?, it's not where RDBMS databases are designed for if you want to use comma separated values you are better off using a text file or a NoSQL database.

Comment: @HoaiNgo ah didn't know that .. never seen anyone use it that way.. seems easier to match col against wanted values rather than compare a value against a function result per row

Comment: "It doesn't matter that you use the col_name or single value like 2, you can double check at " Ok try running `SELECT '1,2,3' IN(2)` which you are basiclly are trying to do here in your data model.  `'1,2,3'` is a single value but i can tell you it does not work that way you need `FIND_IN_SET` see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6xbKtHhNYs8fyBBPGzR18K/2

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` does not use index whereas `IN()` do that, `FIND_IN_SET()` will try find all character in the comma separate string, by the way thank you @RaymondNijland

Comment: "FIND_IN_SET() does not use index whereas IN() do that" read mine other comment " it's not the FIND_IN_SET what makes things slow it's your comma separated values data model which can be hard to index it's can be done with MySQL's generated columns but do you really want to?"

Comment: Yes can use single value, I just try to make my case easy for you guys understand, in pact I do the same idea as you mention @treyBake

Comment: Ok I understand, can you suggest any way to solve my case as long as don't use `FIND_IN_SET` @RaymondNijland

Comment: "Ok I understand, can you suggest any way to solve my case" The other approach would be to make a SQL number generator to split the strings on the comma with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to records (something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890617/restructuring-a-bad-database-with-php-loops-or-mysql/46892143#46892143 post off mine).. Which still would require a full table scan and would be still far away from ideal but then you could copy the records into a temporary table which you can index and search with the `IN()` operator.. But still normalisation should be the way to go here

Comment: because i hope you see now how hard things are going to get when you need to query and search within comma separted values data.. You should really drop using comma separted values from now on and use normalisation..