# How to use 'IN' statement in mySQL cascaded SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, group-concat

I have two tables A and B. I need to pull data from them in a combined statement using GROUP_CONCAT. Currently, it does not work as I expected. So I separated the statement into two seperated simple statements to test.

This is how I did.

```
Tabel A
FIELD1 FIELD
1      A  
2      B
3      C

Table B
FIELD1  FIELD2
1       1,2
2       1
3       2,3
```

I can read the Tabel B as follows

```
SELECT B.FIELD2 FROM B WHERE FIELD1=3
```

Output is

```
FIELD2
2,3
```

Now if I read Tabel A as follows

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.FIELD2) FROM A WHERE FIELD1 IN (2,3)
```

I get

```
FIELD2
B,C
```

Now I want to get the same output with the following statement but it fails.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.FIELD2) FROM A WHERE FIELD1 IN (SELECT B.FIELD2 FROM B WHERE FIELD1=3)
```

Any help fixing the statement?

Comment: Normalize the schema. Read: ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|248.9883)

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly difficult to explain. The IN operator doesn't look at a CSV string in a column and treat it like a comma separated list of values to be looked through. If a column value is some CSV data then the in operator will look for that exact string, commas and everything, in some other list of values

```
2 IN (1,2) --true
'2' IN ('1','2') --true
'2' IN ('1,2') --false 
'1,2' IN ('1,2') --true
```

Always remember that your SQL is compiled like any other program. Data that you write into the statement becomes part of the program. Data in the table does NOT become part of the program. This is why you can't use IN on some comma separated list of stuff you find in a table row

As it stands you'll have to [split the '2,3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936088/mysql-split-comma-separated-list-into-multiple-rows) to two rows of '2' and '3', or keep it as a string and use like

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.FIELD2) 
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B 
  ON CONCAT(',', B.FIELD2, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', A.FIELD1, ',%')
WHERE B.FIELD1=3
```

Nasty! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. This really helps. I think the best is to redesign the table structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can'd do it with the `IN` operator because `B.FIELD2` is not a list of values (which is what `IN` expects) but a string.
You must join the tables and use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.FIELD2) FIELD2
FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON FIND_IN_SET(A.FIELD1, B.FIELD2)
WHERE B.FIELD1 = 3;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1QBGL8yp7QvHANy8HmxVc/5).
Results:

```
| FIELD2 |
| ------ |
| B,C    |
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I need to redesign the table since this has to be in search.  This works but no likely efficient.