# MySQL create view from concat value

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table as follows,

```
+----+-------------+
| id | value       |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | aa,bb,cc,dd |
| 2  | ee,ff,gg,hh |
+----+-------------+
```

I want to be able to search this table to see if `id = 1 AND value = 'cc'`.
Im assuming a good way of doing this is to grab the `id = 1` row and split its values into separate rows in a new view. Something like,

```
+-----+
| val |
+-----+
| aa  |
| bb  |
| cc  |
| dd  |
+-----+
```

I would like to do all of this in MySQL. How can i do this, and is there possibly a better way to do it?

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908966/mysql-procedure-to-load-data-from-staging-table-to-other-tables-need-to-split-u/3909888#3909888

Comment: Someone posted this, but then deleted it. I think its slightly helpful, so ill repost it for the record.

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article might help you solve the problem:

[Mysql split column string into rows](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/)

Instead of this:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
          SELECT table1.id, table1.value
          FROM table1
          WHERE table1.value != '';
```

try this to fit your needs,

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
          SELECT id, value
          FROM table1
          WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good way but you can do string search like this

```
...WHERE id = 1 and 
(value like ',cc,' OR 
 substring(value, -1*LENGTH('cc')-1) = ',cc' OR 
 substring(value, 0, LENGTH('cc')+1) = 'cc,')
```