# Mysql combining data from columns to row

Tags: mysql, row, pivot, copying

The rough structure of the mysql table is like this
Person Name, Mobile Number1, Mob2, Mob3, Mob4.

What I am trying to do is:
For example, if the table has 4 records for the same person like:

```
Person Mob1 Mob2 Mob3 Mob4
John   123  
John   435
John   324
John   432
```

I need to combine the four records into one like:

```
Person  Mob1 Mob2 Mob3 Mob4
John    123  435  324  433
```

Is it possible to do this using a mysql query in phpMyAdmin?
I know it is possible using a php script, but the table is quite huge :close to 500Mb (Nearly a million records.), so a script would be extremely slow/take very long time to complete.

Comment: the number of columns is fixed?

Comment: What do you intend to do with this data once you have pivoted it?

Comment: Is there a person_id column, or is it that names are unique. If there are a million rows, it is unlikely that there is only one  "John Smith"

Comment: reg the no of columns, there are like 20 columns. Reg what I am planning to do it after pivoting it, pivoting the data into a single record, then deleting other records which have empty mob2, mob3, mob4. Reg person_id yes, there is a IC for each person, so I can uniquely identify each person.

Comment: eggyal thanks so much for 'pivot' word. I didnt know this was called pivot operation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a stored procedure, check these other posts for (possibly) helpful info:

- [split keywords for post php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928325/split-keywords-for-post-php-mysql/3929161#3929161)
- [MySQL procedure to load data from staging table to other tables. Need to split up multivalue field in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908966/mysql-procedure-to-load-data-from-staging-table-to-other-tables-need-to-split-u/3909888#3909888)
- [How to expand comma-separated field into multiple rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096584/how-to-expand-comma-separated-field-into-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Or you could try to do it with a function and a group_concat():

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
 LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
 delim, '');
```

And then the select query would be:

```
SELECT
  tmp.id,
  SPLIT_STR(tmp.mobs, ',', 1) as mob1,
  SPLIT_STR(tmp.mobs, ',', 2) as mob2,
  SPLIT_STR(tmp.mobs, ',', 3) as mob3,
  SPLIT_STR(tmp.mobs, ',', 4) as mob4
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(mob1) as mobs
    FROM person
    GROUP BY name
  ) tmp
```

Of course, then you'd have to integrate that into an `UPDATE` statement, but I'll let you try that on your own. (btw, got the `FUNCTION` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two)).

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to use GROUP BY, based my query on it, created a temporary table and voila the mysql query ripped blazing fast to do the job. Thank you so much.